# What are the different levels of the Poké Finder?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

As you know, Pokémon Sun & Moon feature a Poké Finder, which upgrades as you gain likes for your photos.
I'm currently level 4.
So far, the improvements are :

- lvl2 : Zoom
- lvl3 : Better Zoom
- lvl4 : Maximum Zoom.

What happens starting at the fifth level?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Level 5 gives you the ability to press a button to call the Pokemon closer to you. There are no levels higher than level 5.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/5dx1dt/so_i_spent_a_few_hours_grinding_out_the_v5_pok%C3%A9/

Comment: The source you're thinking of is [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/5dx1dt/so_i_spent_a_few_hours_grinding_out_the_v5_pok%C3%A9/).